# Please show full comment in the title attribute( so that I can read comments to me from deleted posts)?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Today some honest and goodly yeoman's comment has been truncated. And I am sad:

Here is proof:

[image]

What happens is that - *I post a comment* , the user responds and then deletes the question.

But it leaves the comment in some aetherial no-mans-land. SAD... it's like saying "Here's some candy buddy!" and then when I reach out "NOPE - DELETED." If Stack wants to truly delete, then they'd also erase any notifications about the comment.

**Request**

As Chris said in comments, to:

> A title attribute on a link will give it a tooltip (hover over the
>   "active" tab below to see it in action).

This way, then even if a user deletes a post - I can still read the comments that they sent me. And I may be able to respond to them.

Comment: Sorry, what is the feature you want?

Comment: The alt text when you hover over it could display the whole comment.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - being able, regardless of reputation, to see any post you have responded to (even if it is deleted) might be an idea.

Comment: Going by the subject question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399285/how-to-move-classes-that-are-in-a-single-java-source-file-into-separate-source-f A more polite outcome than (at least immediate) deletion would have been for cojomojo to invite coffee to post the key idea (try refactoring tools) as an answer.

Comment: The full comment was "I knew there had to be a better term for what I was describing. Thanks @Coffee, it'll definitely help my google searches. I am not fond of coffee however ;) –  cojomojo 1 hour ago"

Comment: Is there anything of the removed posts/comments visible under your [User profile > Responses > Comments](http://stackoverflow.com/users/763029/coffee?tab=responses&sort=comments)?

Comment: @Werner - negative, I see nothing there

Comment: Subject is weird. How about "Show full comment in title attribute"?

Comment: @Chris - Fair enough. I will edit

Comment: @Chris - Ok, i'm a little confused about what "title attribute" means. Isn't it more like "notifications inbox"  or "banner-dropdown" .  What I'd like is to see the full comment , but if it's via some alt text functionality.. then I'm not sure. I'd like to see comment without any barrier(like wait 5 seconds for alt text)

Comment: A title attribute on a link will give it a tooltip (hover over the "active" tab below to see it in action). I thought that is what you are asking for, otherwise, I don't understand what you mean by "simple text file" -- how is the browser going to put a comment in a file, and why would that be a good thing?!

Comment: @Chris - Ok, so my idea was that... because the post got deleted, then that "obsolete" comment can be displayed as plain-text akin to how you see "source formatting" on edit-histories. It's not user-friendly actually, so I'll scratch that idea

Comment: @Chris - Ok so title attribute is fine I think. Will edit

Comment: Earn another 9,304 rep and you won't have this problem any more.

Comment: @Servy - I'd buy that, but this is really an issue of simple consistency. StackOverflow *should not* , regardless of rep, show me something that doesn't exist. It's just a consistency issue at this point. If it's deleted then it should be deleted properly(i.e dont show me a notification )

Comment: @Servy - But overall, if I was commenting back-&_forth at length , i'd really want to view it

Comment: @Coffee If you re-loaded the page, it would be gone.  The issue here is that the question was deleted after the page with the notification was loaded.  It would need to be constantly polling the server to see if each of the posts corresponding to the notification has been deleted, and that's just not a case worth polling for.

Comment: @Servy - Interesting.. hmm, no potential workaround(like just using smaller fonts to show the whole comment? )

Comment: @SylvesterKruin https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @SylvesterKruin If you're not replying to my comments and just want to repeat the feature request then please don't tag me in the comment.

Comment: @Servy: Sorry! Was your caching comment about not seeing the usernames, or was it about about my browser not reloading correctly? There might have been a misunderstanding; I was mainly asking about seeing the usernames. I will repost the comment, and I won't tag you in it :-).

Comment: Could Stack Overflow have a feature where you can, if not read the whole comment, at least have a link to the user who wrote it?

Answer (score -17):

A comment on a deleted question has less utility than a bumper sticker on a scrap metal car, and fewer colors, too. Let's let them rest in peace.

Comment: That's by no means necessarily true.  New users especially delete their questions for inappropriate reasons quite often, and it's more than a little rude to those who have tried to assist them towards a solution.  Higher rep users can at least still see the question, but Coffee would see nothing.

Comment: It's actually a very simple issue though. The system is in an inconsistent state. *If* you don't want to show me the comment, then simply don't show any evidence that the comment existed. And ,I can imagine scenarios where a user invests considerable time into back-&-forth commentating only to have the rug pulled under. Thank you

Comment: @Coffee I agree with your point about consistency. We may differ slightly on how to bring the consistency (I am in favor of removing the notification altogether), but people should not be left hanging.

Comment: As for those who are worried about the information lost in the comment, keep in mind that the system gives users the freedom to delete their own questions. Commenters and answers should let it happen instead of parsing comments for hints that it might have happened for what you, subjectively, feel are the wrong reasons. If you think that askers should not be allowed to delete their own questions on a whim, consider posting a feature request.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - Ideally, there should be a threshold of comment-volume whereby the same "delete-deny" that happens when a real answer is posted